# Loading data step by step

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to load data into my tableview step by step. Just like instagram, loading the first e.g. 15 posts and when a user reaches the bottom of the tableview, load the next 15 posts.
I found this function in the firebase docs called: `queryLimitedToFirst(15)` , but how can I get then next 15 and so on.

Comment: Your question does not give enough detail to provide real answer. StackOverflow is not really a tutorial site, it is designed to help you answer questions about specific coding problems. You may want to search for "UITableView tutorials swift" on the web for helpful tutorials like this one: https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

Comment: What you're describing is known as pagination. It is not easy to build in the Firebase Database API. But have a look at the previous questions on the topic to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bswift%5D+pagination

Comment: The problem is not the tableview thing, I could figure that out. The problem is the query! How can I load the first 15 and then the next 15, and so on.. I know this is not a tutorial site but I was having this problem and had no clue at all how to solve it, so I asked here.

Answer (score 0):

In tableview controller when tableview scroll reaches at the end this function is called which loads more reusable cells

```
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
     if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= self.tableView.contentSize.height - self.tableView.bounds.size.height {     
         loadMore()
  } 

  func loadMore() {
  your api call to load more
  }
```